Class_weight parameter not impacting results in imbalanced dataset with RandomForestClassifier
I'm fairly new to ML and now I'm in the process of predicting employee attrition in a medium sized dataset. I have been able to run everything smoothly, but, as the dataset is imbalanced, I've been trying to add weights to the model, so I get more recall in the positive class, by loosing some precission. The problem comes when I try to do that in scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier, I've tried different ways, by creating an standalone dict for the values, adding the dict directly to the parameters and it is not affecting the model at all. The results always stay the same, with the majority class getting always better results than the minority class.
With other models I'm not having the problem at all.
Is there something I'm doing wrong here?
(This is the dataset I'm using, if it helps anyone: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/bhanupratapbiswas/hr-analytics-case-study )
The code for the model:
#Running the model with the best hyperparameters
weight_dict = {0: 0.59, 1: 3.12}

model = RandomForestClassifier(bootstrap=False, criterion='gini', max_depth=24, max_features='log2', min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2, n_estimators=200, class_weight=weight_dict)
model.fit(X_train_smote, y_train_smote)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test_outliers)

#Printing the results
print('Accuracy:', accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
print('AUC-ROC Score:', roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred))
print('Classification Report:', classification_report(y_test, y_pred))

#Plotting the confusion matrix
plt.figure()
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred), annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues')
plt.xlabel('Predicted label')
plt.ylabel('True label')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

I'm expecting more recall in the minority class and loosing some precission and recall in the majority class.
I have checked past questions and answers, but I already have applied the solutions from different answers with no succes.
Thank you!

After your suggestion, I have tried BalancedRandomForestClassifier and I'm facing the same problem. Even though I put more weight on the minority class, the model still acts as if it didn't receive the weight parameters. I have also added the different values to sampling_strategy and still the same.

@DataJanitor Got it! Thank you so much. I have also found that I was using data already balanced using SMOTE, and using the data that was not already balanced improved the results a lot for the BalancedRandomForestClassifier. Again, thank you!

How big is the dataset? // Compare the predicted probabilities from the models with different weights.
